# how to get sub-category values for a particular category using select tag in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, combobox

I have two combo box , one for main category and other for sub category. Now , i want user to select main category whose values are coming from database ,  and based on that particular category, sub-category(from db) should be shown on the second combo box.

I have tried using java script as shown below:

```
     <script>
       function byId(e) {return document.getElementById(e);}

       function stateComboChange()
      {
  var combo1 = byId('stateCombo');  //main category combo id
  var combo2 = byId('cityCombo');    //sub category combo id
  //  alert(combo1.value);

  emptyCombo(combo2);
  switch(combo1.value)
  {
    case '-1':  addOption(combo2, -1, '-select state first-');
                break;
    case '0':   addOption(combo2,'Nokia');
                addOption(combo2, 'Samsung');
                addOption(combo2, 'Sony');
                addOption(combo2, 'Iphone 5');
                addOption(combo2, 'Lava');
                addOption(combo2, 'Micromax');

                break;
    case '1':   addOption(combo2, 'Edge Router');
                addOption(combo2, 'Subscriber Edge Router');
                addOption(combo2, 'Inter-provider Border Router');
                addOption(combo2, 'Core Router');
                addOption(combo2, 'Wired and Wireless Routers');

                break;
    case '2':       addOption(combo2, 'MTS');
                addOption(combo2, 'Docomo');
                addOption(combo2, 'Airtel');
                addOption(combo2, 'Photon');
                addOption(combo2, 'Idea');
                addOption(combo2, 'Vodafone');

                break;


}
cityComboChange();

//  var Cat = document.getElementById('stateCombo').value;
    document.getElementById('catvalue').value = combo1.value;
```

}

```
       function emptyCombo(e)
      {
         e.innerHTML = '';
      }
```

here i need to know how can i implement this add option function , so that values from db is shown on that 2nd combo box. right now this is manually.

```
       function addOption(combo, txt)
         {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = txt;
        option.title = txt;
       option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
         combo.appendChild(option);
           }

        </script>
```

or can anyone suggest best possible solution for this.

Comment: Is there any problem with this implementation? If so, can you update your post with a specific question? If not (and merely meant as review), please head to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @mthmulders problem here is i want to implement the above addOption function as shown the above script, such that values should be shown according to the selected main category from first combo box, right now I've to enter values manually in the script.

Comment: You need to make an AJAX call to server to fetch the sub-catagory. Then populate those to the dropdown.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao how can i make ajax call  to server ? can you explain it little bit?

Comment: Checkout my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086665/ajax-precondition-failed-error/19090463#19090463). Here i am using jquery plugin for sending the ajax requests. May this help you.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan thanks let me check